# Editing Tumblr theme's HTML to accommodate transparency

Tags: html, png, transparency, tumblr

I have a Tumblr blog, and I'm using the [Effector](http://effectortheme.tumblr.com/) theme. I like it, but unfortunately it colors [the backgrounds of all partially transparent images black](http://droosy.tumblr.com/post/49381495718). Is there any way I can edit the theme's HTML so that it makes transparent backgrounds white? I looked through the code already, but I think I need someone more familiar with HTML to give me advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking up the tree from the element, you only need to make one change for it to be white, and that’s in the `.photo-panel` rule:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

Change `rgb(0, 0, 0)` to `transparent`, or just remove that rule entirely.

(For full transparency, also remove the `background` rule on `.post .post-panel`, and probably its `box-shadow` too.)

Comment: OK, thanks! But I couldn't find the relevant code in the "Edit HTML" app. Should I edit the HTML using some other method? Sorry, but I'm completely clueless about this language.

Comment: @cutiemarxism: Perhaps you can override it by redefining the rule? Sorry, but I’m completely clueless about Tumblr :D

Comment: I would suggest using the Custom CSS pane. This would override anything css set in the themes HTML.